# i want to return 0 when a key is not found instead of "key not found" error in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, I want to divide it into chunks of 400 and get the count of a key.
my data frame looks like this df= [key{ e, r, t, g, h},value{1,3,2,4}]

```
while i<df['key'].count():
    if((df.index.contains('R')[i:i+400])):
        count = df['key'][i:i+400].value_counts().loc['R']
    else:
        count='0'
    i=i+400
    print(count)
```

but I get the error if the key is not in a particular chunk of 400. how do I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `try except`.

```
try:
    while i<df['key'].count():
        df.index.contains('R')[i:i+400]
        count = df['key'][i:i+400].value_counts().loc['R']
        i=i+400
except KeyNotFoundError:
    count='0'

print(count)
```

You can pass error if you want.